# Base JavaFX applet size on node size

Tags: javafx

When embedding JavaFX in javascript, is there a way to base the height and width on the size of the JavaFX stage? So if I were to update the dimensions of my stage, I wouldn't have to edit the javascript as well.

Conversely, is there a way to bind the dimensions of my stage to the dimensions of the user's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to set the applet up like so:

```
javafx(
  {
    archive: "myapp.jar",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    code: "my.app.myapp",
    id: "app"
  }
);
```

which worked just fine for filling the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript options is one named `show_html`. When setted to `true`, the script will show you the HTML. Once you have it, you can apply **CSS styles** to it and use the HTML instead of the JS.